# Apple App Upload Icon Validation Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm uploading a free app to the Mac App Store and I keep getting this error during validation that says,

> The application bundle does not contain an icon in ICNS format, containing both a `512x512` and a `512x512@2x` image. For further assistance, see the Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

The only thing is, there are files called `icon_512x512.png` and `icon_512x512@2x.png`, as well as files for all the other necessary resolutions.

Since Apple is absolutely no help, I was hoping someone would know how to fix this or at least go about creating an icon that meets the specifications.

Answer (score 7):

As I understand it, if you create the .icns in Icon Composer it will fail validation even if a proper `512x512@2x` is present. Use iconutil to convert the .icns back into an iconset, and then use iconutil to create a new .icns from the iconset.

For instance:

```
resources $ iconutil -c iconset icon.icns
resources $ iconutil -c icns icon.iconset
```

More info on iconutil is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html).

Answer (score 3):

That fixed my problem but I used `cd` to go to the folder, then I entered

```
iconutil -c iconset icon.icns
iconutil -c icns icon.iconset
```

the icon name must be icon as in the command.

Answer (score 1):

you should prepare 2 pictures with png extension, one is 512x512 pixels named icon_512x512.png, one is  1024x1024 pixels named icon_512x512@2x.png, put the 2 pictures in a folder(named icon for example), then out the folder use command `iconutil -c icns icon`, you will get a icon.icns, drag it to Xcode and drop on the target's App icon.

Comment: Yeah I did that and that didn't work either. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you include the .icns file extension in your plist when specifying the name of your icon. At some point this became required by iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

just create the icon 1024x1024 then add that icon to the folder Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

After these you will see the icon under xcode as "unsigned"

just drag that icon to empty icon field. thats it .

[image]